# Can an intrinsic compiler function be weakly defined or does Clang not respect weak attributes?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, clang

Say there's a function _foo which:

- Is intrinsic to the Clang version I'm using, and
- Is is not defined in the GCC version.

I'd like to have my code compile for both Clang and GCC and various versions.

I would expect that:

```
__attribute__((weak)) _foo (...) { my_foo(...); }
```

To allow me to use the Clang version if compiling with Clang, but use my_foo if using a compiler that does not have it as an intrinsic (e.g. my current GCC version).

The problem is that Clang thinks I'm redefining _foo.

I could ifdef off of __ clang __ but my concern is that for GCC versions that do have _foo as an intrinsic, compilation will break due to the same redefinition error.

So the question is:

- Does the weak attribute not work with intrinsic functions? or
- Clang does not respect the weak attribute?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `is that for GCC versions that do have _foo as an intrinsic, compilation will break due to the same redefinition error` It's normal, called "porting", and yes, then you'll do `#if defined(__clang__) || __GNUC__ < some_versionull`.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the weak attribute not work with intrinsic functions?

Yes, the function is not linked, it is intrinsic.

> Clang does not respect the weak attribute?

Clang understands weak attribute.

> I could ifdef off of __ clang __ but my concern is that for GCC versions that do have _foo as an intrinsic, compilation will break due to the same redefinition error.

So then you will `#if` specific gcc version. [This is how it works](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/895ef79e04a953cac1493863bcae29ad85657ee1/misc/sys/cdefs.h#L342). Some "intrinsic function" is not standard so do not expect a standard ultimate way of handling it. If you are using *compiler specific* feature, you will be handling each compiler separately, as, well, it *is* compiler specific.

But the approach is wrong overall. Rather then providing compiler specific function in reserved namespace as most probably you intent to, provide your own wrapper that optionally uses compiler specific function if possible:

```
 void foo(int arg) {
    #if defined(__clang__) && __clang_major__ > 4 // handle specific compiler versions
    // #if CONFIG_HAS_BUILTIN_FOO      // or use build system
        __builtin_foo(arg);
    #else 
        standard_compliant_algortihm();
    #endif
 }
 // use foo(arg) in your code
```

See ex. [byteswap.h](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/bits/byteswap.h#L51) from top of my head. Providing a symbol in reserved namespace in `__*` or `_<UPPER CASE LETTER>*` is undefined behavior. Do not do it. It's namespace specially reserved for compilers to use, specially so that users do not use them. Do not provide symbols in that namespace.

In general to be portable, you would use `cmake` ([`CheckSymbolExists(__builtin_foo)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckSymbolExists.html)) or `autotools` or other build system to *detect* if the compiler supports specific builtin and optionally use it in your code if the compiler supports it.